# How to replace html with class and id names inside div

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know if this is possible, I know how to replace html tags, and replace id and/or class names. But is it possible to replace a block of html code with class and id names in it? My code doesn't work, I don't know why..

I have this code right here

```
//This is the code that I want to replace, inside the graph_analysis
<div class="card mt-12" id="graph_analysis">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
       <canvas id="bar-chart-grouped" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
        <p id='analysis-text'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//This is the jQuery code where the user triggers the function, it should replace the existing block of code inside the div graph_analysis
$("#graph_analysis").html(" <div class='card-img-top img-fluid' style='width: 100%; height: 50%;'><canvas id='bar-chart-grouped' width='100%' height='50%'></canvas></div><div class='card-body'><div class='row'><p id='analysis-text'></p></div></div> ");
```

Comment: yes its possible ! to replace block of html code

Comment: Your code is perfect,

Comment: your code is working fine. Just add some data in the div which is to be inserted and you can see for yourself

Comment: Can you be more specific that "My code doesn't work"? What happens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen that should? What console errors are you getting?

Comment: Just write your jQuery operations inside this `$(document).ready(function(){   // your code goes here   });`

Comment: What does the user do to trigger the replacement? Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55096151/edit) then the snippet editor `[<>]` to create a [mcve]

Comment: I think I do need the $(document).ready part, it seems to be working, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Please delete the question - it is not useful for anyone else and solicited a lot of wrong answers. _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_